# Strom on Mesos in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-storm, mesos, mesosphere

I am running a storm cluster on AWS. But I want the storm cluster to expand automatically when the need comes. I figured out mesos is something like that. But I do not have much knowledge about mesos and its deployment on AWS.

Can mesos on AWS automatically increase the parallelism of my topology tasks by launching new instances and shutting them down when not necessary? If it can, how do we configure mesos for the same.

Comment: Bhargav, it is going to be difficult for anyone to answer all of your questions. I recommend breaking this down into ONE question that can be easily answered.

Answer (score 1):

Mesos does not directly handle autoscaling itself, but allows frameworks running on top of it to receive new resource offers and react to them by launching new task instances. I haven't used it personally, but you could try the Storm-Mesos framework for running Storm on Mesos: https://github.com/mesos/storm

Once you have Storm running on Mesos, ready to launch new instances as resources come available, you're ready to autoscale within the existing cluster's capacity. You'll probably want to take advantage of Amazon's Auto-Scaling Groups (ASGs) to scale up the number of Mesos nodes based on your need. As the ASG scales up more Mesos nodes, the resources from those nodes will be automatically offered to the Storm-Mesos framework, which can launch more Storm instances.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're heading in the right direction. However I'd suggest to use [Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/) rather than the low-level Mesos API.

See for example the GitHub repo [obaidsalikeen/storm-marathon](https://github.com/obaidsalikeen/storm-marathon), which is particularly well done in terms of completeness and documentation richness.